# Difference between android:id, android:name and name tags in Android XML files

Tags: android, android-xml

Can someone clarify the difference between `android:id`, `android:name` and `name` tags in Android's XML files. They all seem to be ways to reference things.

For example, when I have a string array in the `res/values/array.xml` file I access using the `name` field in the defined array yet the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray(int)) refers to this as the "ID".

`android:id` seems to be just used in `View`s ?

Am I missing something or would it not be simpler to have one tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't believe you're missing anything. Although these fields are named differently, it's my understanding that they are both used to identify/reference resources. This specifically means GUI elements (views) in the case of `android:id` and static resources in the case of `name`.

To go into more depth, I believe the `android:id` attribute is assigned only to Views and classes that extend View.  This is done so that the view can be programmatically accessed from your code using `findViewById`:

`Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.whatever_id_assigned_to_view)`

This is different from resources such as strings.xml or array.xml which are identified simply by `name`, such as a following example of what might be found in strings.xml:

`<string name="string_name">Text Resource Here</string>`

and is accessed using...

`getResources().getText(R.string.string_name)`

I imagine these are separated for organizational reasons. This way the generated Android resource file (R.java) contains the IDs specified for views in R.id, the string IDs contained in R.string, array IDs in R.array etc.

Comment: Thanks for the Jordan. I think that has cleared things up for me. And it looks like `android:name` is just used in manifest file also.

Comment: The 'name'' property has other functions as well. For example, in fragments it is used to specify the class to instantiate in the layout: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: This doesn't ATQ for the `android:tag` fields that can be used with `Fragments`.  Looks like `:id` is preferred: [View#android:tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:tag)

Comment: More on the usefulness of the `:tag` attribute: [Adding Fragments without a UI](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#AddingWithoutUI)