# What does android:name tag mean and how can it be used?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I was looking through navigation in Android studio and I came across this tag but had no idea what the point of it was.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/home_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" //this one here
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/home_nav_graph" />
```

Comment: The android:name attribute in the <fragment> specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107616/difference-between-androidid-androidname-and-name-tags-in-android-xml-files
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

It specifies which fragment class should be instantiated in the layout.

You can learn more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)